# How to print data from list stored in redis?

Tags: python, redis

My data has been stored in list 'lst' in redis.

I have to print all elements of list

```
for i in range(0,r_server.llen('lst')):
    print ??????
```

What do I write in for loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach is valid but ineffective - you'll be doing a lot of needless requests, thus wasting CPU, bandwidth and time. If your `lst` hast N elements, your loop will require N+1 calls to redis out of which N calls will be to [`LINDEX`](http://redis.io/commands/lindex) whose complexity is O(N).

Redis offers a better way to do that with the [`LRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) command, so you can basically replace all calls to Redis with a single call to it, likeso:

```
l = redis_server.lrange('lst', 0, -1)
for x in l:
  print x
```

Note, however, that doing this with large lists is also problematic because you'll be blocking Redis while it prepares the reply to the `LRANGE` request (+ consuming memory for the reply's buffer). In such cases you should consider using the circular list pattern with [`RPOPLPUSH`](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) on `lst` or a copy of it, with or without concurrency considerations.

Answer (score 0):

A quicker way would be:

```
for item in redis_server.lrange('lst', 0, -1):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for e in r.lrange( 'LanguageList', 0, -1 ):
    print(e)
```

Comment: Hi, could you add some explanation on what this solution adds to the previous answer (from ~5 years ago)?